# How to include a script into my cshtml file without all the script texts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, razor

I have a asp.net cshtml file but I have to include script html's with ids for my ngRoutes to work. So far my cshtml file looks like this:

```
<div ng-view></div>

<script type="text/ng-template id="one.html">
...very long html...
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template id="two.html">
...very long html...
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template id="three.html">
...very long html...
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template id="four.html">
...very long html...
</script>
```

I don't want to include all the script, but need it to display like a directive.  How am I able to do something like...

```
<div ng-view></div>
<div ng-include="'one.html''"></div>
<div ng-include="'two.html''"></div>
<div ng-include="'three.html''"></div>
```

I've tried that way but it doesn't allow me to just include it in the razor file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using ngRoute. In this case you can set the template urls on the routeProvider during the config phase:

```
angular.module('yourmodule', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/one', {
            templateUrl: 'one.html',
        })
        .when('/two', {
            templateUrl: 'two.html',
        });
}])
```

Comment: I am using ngRoute, but when I put the path to the file in the templateurl, it doesn't load the routing link correctly on my server but does on my local. I really want to keep all my templates in a separate html file but when I release it on the server I have issues when it works just fine locally. It works fine if I include the script with the id under the <div ng-view></div>  locally and on the server

Comment: That's probably a paths issue. templateUrl needs to contain the full path to the file as seen from the client (browser). If your application is in a subdirectory, you need to add these to the template paths. You can check this in your favorite browser's developer tools.

Comment: I guess I have to configure the route so that if it's on the localhost, it'll use the leading slash in the when clause and when in the test server host, set it to not use the leading slash. ngRoute will not allow variables in the when clause, so that way I can do if host is localhost use / else set to "" at the beginning.